# Сохранение изображений с сайта на жесткий диск

Tags: c#, selenium

Здравствуйте. Передо мной стоит задача: сохранить несколько изображений из выданных результатов в поиске Google. Каким образом это можно сделать? Сколько ни пытался, сохраняет либо превью, либо вообще не получается. Пытался через:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(path, @"...");
```

Так не вышло, выдает ошибку, типа "access to path denied". Плюс, когда я через GetAttribute("src") запрашиваю URL картинки, выдает только превью. А мне нужен оригинал. Если запрашивать GetAttribute("href"), ошибка: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString. Также пытался через:

```
//saveImage = ImageIO.read();
//ImageIO.write(saveImage "...", new File("..."));
```

Так тоже не получается. Может быть я что-то неправильно делаю. Просто я в этом деле сильно начинающий и пока совсем мало знаю. Буду благодарен, если распишете.

Вот полностью код. Что я делаю не так?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Internal;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Selenium.Sample
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    ChromeDriver chrome;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        chrome.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        chrome.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("фото дня" + Keys.Enter);
        chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.hdtb-mitem:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)")).Click();
        chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#abar_button_opt")).Click();
        chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lb > div > a:nth-child(3)")).Click();
        chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#imgsz_button")).Click();
        chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=':7d']")).Click();
        chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.bottom-wrapper > div._Vkb > form > div:nth-child(8) > div:nth-child(10) > div._Ai > input")).Click();
        //chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#rg_s > div:nth-child(1) > a > img")).Click();
    }
    public void search(string query = null);
    {
        const string url = "https://ww.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=";
    var chrome = new ChromeDriver();
    chrome.Navigate(url + query);
        while (chrome.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
        {
            ApplicationId.DoEvents();
        }
```

}

Comment: P.S. Работаю в Selenium 3 на C#

Comment: добавьте деталей в вопрос (*как именно пытался и тп*) и вместо комментариев используйте "*править*" для дополнений к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал **готовый парсер на C#** без использования сторонних библиотек. 
Код предполагает создание формы и двух компонентов на ней: текстовое поле "textBoxQuery" для ввода ключа и "кнопки "buttonLoad" для запуска парсера".
Использован компонент WebBrowser для получения исходного кода.
Регулярное выражение для парсинга ссылок на картинки, так как по динамическому ID гугл её получить нет возможности.
WebClient для загрузки изображения, и сохранения их с оригинальным именем.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DownloadImageFromGoogle
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            search(textBoxQuery.Text);
        }

        private List<string> getLinks(string source)
        {
            var links = new List<string>();
            Regex a = new Regex(@"(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[\w\.]+)\.(?:[a-z]{2,6}\.?)(?:\/[\w\.]*)*\/?");
            Match m = a.Match(source);
            while (m.Success)
            {
                var img = m.Value;
                if (img.StartsWith("http") && (img.EndsWith("png") || img.EndsWith("jpg")))
                    links.Add(img);
                m = m.NextMatch();
            }

            return links;
        }

        private void search(string Query = null)
        {
            string url = $"https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=ru&as_q={Query}&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&tbs=isz:lt,islt:2mp";
            var wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Navigate(url);
            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            string textHtml = wb.DocumentText;
            var links = getLinks(textHtml);

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                foreach (var link in links)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(link, "images/" + Path.GetFileName(link));
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот это даа. Огромное спасибо. Кстати, почему-то помечает InitializeComponent и textBoxQuery. Я добавил референсы, но на это не знаю, какой.

Comment: на форму добавьте TextBox  получите textBox1 переименованный = textBoxQuery.  и копку  buttonLoad  создайте событие Click

Comment: Прошу прощения. А нельзя ли все же как-то через Selenium это провернуть? Просто это обязательное условие. Неделю уже бьюсь над этим...

Comment: Можно конечно , но это же парсер ! код который предложил я можно запустить в 1000 потоков, и он будет работать , и не будет перегружать систему. А один экземпляр селениум съест столько ресурсов в один поток. Напишите мне в чат , что-то придумаю

Comment: А здесь есть чат?

Comment: Ясно, я не могу в чате общаться, репутации не хватает. Нужно 20

Comment: Я просмотрел ваш код , остановил выполнение на форме расширенного поиска, вы же никак не обращаетесь к ссылке и их не парсите . Ваш кот просто серфит страницы , вводит запрос переходит .
Для парсинга необходимо указать параметры ссылок (класс , ид, тег)сохранить их в массив, после пройти массив циклом , скачать , и сохранить изображение.

Comment: Для меня это пока темный лес.  Если не затруднит,  можете привести примеры? Как это делается.

Comment: Я поизучал это все, но все равно нигде не нашел примеров, применительно к моей задаче. Везде все в общих чертах, частный случай не найти. Может покажете пример, применимый к моей задаче, если на затруднит?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос относится не к программированию, и не к языку C#, вы наверное ожидаете код - решение. Код увы не предоставлю, зато поясню как работает поисковик гугл, и почему у вас налл референс ! 
Поисковая машина гугл не держит на своих серверах полных изображений , когда при поиске в браузере отображаются изображения-картинки, они подгружаются из целевого ресурса на котором расположены. Гугл же выдаёт страницу с шифрованным JS, и миниатюру , если в браузере обрабатывается JS, браузер подгружает картинку из ресурса где она расположена по событию onClick();

С загрузкой картинки отлично справиться вами-же приведённый код.

```
private void Download(string url = null)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(url, Path.GetFileName(url));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за то, что отозвались. Но я всё-таки недопонял. В ЯП я полный ноль, я только начинаю изучение.
Не компилируется. Он не воспринимает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я закинул код полностью в вопрос.

Comment: Для парсинга не рентабельно тянуть за собой драйвер целого браузера, большой расход ресурсов .  Сд. на силениум , код который я привёл предполагает использование компонентов дот нет - без сторонних библиотек., и драйверов.